# OpenCV2 with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to get OpenCV2 running with Eclipse. My code works when I compile it directly with command-line.

Here is the code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat test = imread("pyramids.jpg");

    imshow("test", test);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

With command line I compile it as --

```
 g++ hello_opencv2.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags`
```

Now, I am trying to achieve the with Eclipse. Please help me setup the build environment. 
I am unable to find a dialog which will allow me to set CFLAGS & LIBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a good explanation about how to setup OpenCV with Eclipse on OpenCV [Online documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#linux-eclipse-usage)

Comment: actually, am wanting to use CUDA and OpenCV2. I could use opencv2 only. However when I create another file name "file.cu" I get following error -- make all 
Building file: ../file.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc  -G -g -O0  -odir "" -M -o "file.d" "../file.cu"
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc -G -g -O0   "file.o" "../file.cu"
g++: error: file.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [file.o] Error 1